# Cannot choose HoloLens Emulator as debug target in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2015, emulation, hyper-v, hololens, hololens-emulator

I have Visual Studio 2015 Update 2, and HoloLens Emulator is in the list of debug target, however when I click on it, nothing happens. No error, no log in Output or Error Window.

In Hyper-V, I cannot see any virtual machine in the list, everything is blank. I have tried to uninstall and install the Emulator again, everything is successful but I still cannot choose that target.

Also, in Unity, I see no Windows Holographic option in the Render section of Player Settings. I can run the Windows Phone Emulator just fine though, and Hyper-V seems to be fine (but I am not sure).

Is there any way to run the emulator as standalone, without Visual Studio? Or anyone has met this problem and been able to solve it?

Comment: I'm having the same issue too except in my case I don't even have the option to select the HoloLens emulator in VS. I've tried both online and offline installs, but it still just doesn't show up.

Comment: @Generalkidd Did you successfully upgrade to Update 2? Also, I think you need something like WindowsSDK installed too.

Comment: It worked for me when I upgraded to Update 2 as well as when I did a clean install of Visual Studio with Update 2. And yes you need the Windows SDK installed as well.

Answer (score 2):

I believe I have figured out the solution. The HoloLens emulator doesn't show up for me if I simply create a HoloLens DirectX application in Visual Studio. However, if I load up a standard Universal App project, even an older project, the HoloLens emulator shows up as a target for me and it works great. Try creating a standard Windows 10 Universal App and see if the HoloLens emulator shows up as an option to target. Also make sure you set your target platform to x86 in order for the HoloLens emulator to work.

Comment: I already creaed a Universal App (Windows 10 I assume). The target is always there, but I cannot choose it (clicking on it does nothing, as if I didn't click on it). I tried Holographic DirectX project as well. The target list has HoloLens Emulator, but clicking on it does nothing too. Also, I aready target x86.

Comment: Are you have any compilation errors with your project? Can you post a screenshot of what the issue looks like?

Answer (score 2):

I experienced this same exact issue when I did the initial Hololens setup on my laptop

The emulator was in the list and clicking on it produced nothing. This proved to be a systematic issue, i.e. reinstalling the tools from scratch [in the same way] didn't help me. And I had different behaviors depending on how I was going to install the [recommended](https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjF8qrX5o3PAhURHGMKHcGlDJYQFggbMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fwindows%2Fholographic%2Finstall_the_tools&usg=AFQjCNEmgSVwLHd9xkbkwf5jHXTFUfxqjQ&bvm=bv.132479545,d.dGo) tools. For example a different behavior if the WindowsSDK was installed via Visual Studio 2015 or as [standalone](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk)

Unfortunately I could not detect what was exactly wrong but reading online from other users I was convinced to factory reset the laptop and reinstall the tools on the clean Windows10 installation

Now everything is perfectly working. Let me know your outcome